# evaluate a Fraunhofer diffraction integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

I need to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{rect}(\frac{x'}{2w}) \exp\left (\frac{im}{2}\sin \left(k_Gx' \right)  \right )\exp\left (-\frac{ik}{z}xx'  \right )dx'$$

where $\text{rect}$ is the Rectangle function, as defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangleFunction.html).

This integral becomes (because of $\text{rect}$ values):
$$\int_{-w}^w \exp\left (\frac{im}{2}\sin \left(k_Gx' \right)  \right )\exp\left (-\frac{ik}{z}xx'  \right )dx'$$

I may use the following identity for my solution:
$$\exp\left (\frac{im}{2}\sin \left(k \right)\right)=\sum_{q=-\infty}^\infty J_q(\frac{m}{2})\exp\left(iqkx\right)$$
Where $J_q$ is [Bessel Function of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

I need some help working it out.
This is a Fraunhofer diffraction from a slit with the transfer function $t(x)=\text{rect}(\frac{x}{2w}) \exp\left (\frac{im}{2}\sin \left(k_Gx \right)  \right )$.

Comment: Was going to provide a possible solution, but I realize I'm confused about a few things.  1) n in your summation does not appear in your expression.  This can't be right.  2) Should x in the summation be x-prime?  3) Where does $k_G$ go?  I am tempted to say that once you make the substitution, the integrand becomes a sum of straightforward exponentials, but I'm not sure.

Comment: 1 - You are right, I edited the summation variable. 2- Edited. 3- I don't clearly understand. $k_G \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I mean that in the summation expression, you have a $k_G$ on the LHS, but not on the RHS.  Should the $k$ on the RHS be $k_G$?

Comment: You are right. It should be simply $k$ on both sides. Edited original Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you substitution and pull the sum out of the integral to get

$\displaystyle \sum_q J_q(\frac{m}{2})\int_{-w}^w dx^\prime \exp(i(qk_G-\frac{kx}{z})x^\prime)$

Now each integral is a straightforward integral of a complex exponential:

$\displaystyle \int_{-w}^w dx^\prime ... = \frac{2i\sin((qk_G-kx/z)w)}{qk_G-kx/z}$

So you just have a series of terms, each one being a Bessel function multiplied by the coefficient you get from the integrals.  Honestly, I'm now at my limits.  I suspect that the sum can be evaluated or well-approximated by some piece of other information you have been given.